# Can't link program, glLinkProgram() give me GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c, opengl

I'm currently learning OpenGL 3.X, i'm working on ubuntu 14.04.
I'm using C language to create my application and SDL2 library.

The command

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

Gives me the following output

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
```

I have a problem with my shaders creation, here is the code that load/compile/link shaders:

```
typedef struct  s_shader
{
   GLuint  vertex_id;
   GLuint  fragment_id;
   GLuint  program_id;
}               t_shader;

t_shader    *create_shader(const char *vertex_file, const char *fragment_file)
{
    t_shader    *new_shader;

    new_shader = (t_shader *)malloc(sizeof(t_shader));
    if (new_shader)
    {
        new_shader->vertex_id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        new_shader->fragment_id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        new_shader->program_id = glCreateProgram();
        load_shader(new_shader, vertex_file, fragment_file);
        glCompileShader(new_shader->vertex_id);
        glCompileShader(new_shader->fragment_id);
        glAttachShader(new_shader->program_id, new_shader->vertex_id);
        glAttachShader(new_shader->program_id, new_shader->fragment_id);
        glLinkProgram(new_shader->program_id);
    }
    return (new_shader);
}

void        load_shader(t_shader *shader,const char *vertex_file,const char *fragment_file)
{
    char    *vertex_file_content;
    char    *fragment_file_content;
    int     vertex_len;
    int     fragment_len;

    vertex_file_content = NULL;
    fragment_file_content = NULL;
    vertex_file_content = get_file_content(vertex_file);
    fragment_file_content = get_file_content(fragment_file);
    vertex_len = strlen(vertex_file_content);
    fragment_len = strlen(fragment_file_content);

    glShaderSource(shader->vertex_id, 1, (const GLchar **)&vertex_file_content, &vertex_len);
    glShaderSource(shader->fragment_id, 1, (const GLchar **)&fragment_file_content, &fragment_len);
}
```

I use a glGetError() after each gl call, and the first error code i got is with the glLinkProgram() call, it gives me an GL_INVALID_OPERATION (error 1282).
I tried to output the log error with like this:

```
    GLchar    buff[1024];
    GLsizei     length;
    glGetProgramInfoLog(new_shader->program_id, 1024, &length, buff);
    printf("length:%i\nlog:'%s'\n", length, buff);
```

But the log is empty.

I used the glIsShader() for both fragment and vertex shader, it return GL_TRUE.
I also use glGetShaderInfoLog() after glCompileShader() and the logs are empty for both fragment and vertex shader.
I read in the documentation that:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if program is not a program object.
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if program is the currently active program object and transform feedback mode is active.

My program seems to be a program object because glCreateProgram return a non null value.
At this moment in the code, there is no active program object.

Window and OpenGL context:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

window = SDL_CreateWindow("My OpenGl", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
if (window)
{
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
  gl_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
```

Here is the function that reads file content:

```
char        *get_file_content(const char *file_name)
{
    FILE    *file;
    char    *file_content;
    long    file_size;

    file = NULL;
    file_content = NULL;
    file_size = 0;
    file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (file)
    {
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        file_size = ftell(file);
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        file_content = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * file_size + 1);
        if (file_content)
        {
            memset(file_content, '\0', file_size);
            fread(file_content, sizeof(char), file_size, file);
            file_content[file_size + 1] = '\0';
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    return (file_content);
}
```

Fragment shader source:

```
#version 150 core

in vec3 color;
out vec4 out_Color;

void main()
{
    out_Color = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0);
}
```

Vertex shader source:

```
#version 150 core

in vec3 in_Vertex;
in vec3 in_Color;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelview;

out vec3 color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * modelview * vec4(in_Vertex, 1.0);
    color = in_Color;
}
```

Is there any other way to debug glLinkProgram?

Comment: There are lots of other conditions which might trigger that error. Check the shader compilation status and logs. It might also help if you actually oosted the shader source codes.

Comment: Can you post the vertex and fragment shader source? Have you checked their compile logs with glGetShaderInfoLog?

Comment: I edited the question, and added fragment and vertex shaders sources. I also use glGetShaderInfoLog() and glIsShader() for debugging.

Comment: Unlikely that it causes your problem, but you are writing one byte beyond the allocated memory in `get_file_content()`. The zero terminator should be assigned as `file_content[file_size] = '\0';`.

Answer (score 3):

Your shaders might fail to compile because you are trying to use  GLSL `#version 150` (which was introduced along with OpenGL 3.2) in an OpenGL 3.0 context.

Since you are using mesa, chances are that your GPU actually supports 3.2 or higher. But on mesa, you must use a *core* profile to get access to OpenGL >= 3.2 contexts. Without that, mesa will be limited to GL 3.0, and this is exactly what you got.

So you have two alternatives:

1. Downgrade your shaders to `#version 130`. With the shaders you posted, I don't see anything which would not work with that version, so adjusting just the `#version` directive should be enough.
2. Upgrade your context to modern GL 3.2 core profile. Since you are using SDL2, the relevant function is [`SDL_GL_SetAttribute()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_SetAttribute), see also [the `SDL_GLprofile` documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GLprofile). Using a core profile means that all deprecated functions are not available any more. You did not post your code, so it is unclear if relies on deprecated functionality or not.

While alternative 1 might seem simpler, I strongly recommend to go for variant 2. If you are learning GL nowadays, you should learn the new way, and not the deprecated cruft from over a decade ago.

Comment: I tried your first alternative but it didn't change anything.
I also tried the SDL_GLprofile to use a core profile (i added the code to my question). But now my shaders failed to compile: "error: GLSL 1.50 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, and 1.00 ES"

Comment: Well, you actually need to request GL version 3.2 additionally.  The error message suggests that you are still on GL 3.0.

Comment: Now, i don't have any erros on Shaders compilation anymore. Also, glGetString(GL_VERSION) returns "3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.3" and glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) returns "3.30". So i assume that i'm at 3.3 now, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Now the question is that if a) the GLSL version was the only issue and b) your code is not relying on deprecated functionality not available in a core profile.

Comment: I don't think i use any deprecated functions, but how can i check that?
And how a deprecated function can make my glLinkProgram() failed?

Comment: Are you sure that the `glLinkProgram()` is actually causing the `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` erro,r, i.e. have you checked that the GL error state before that call is actually `GL_NO_ERROR`? I don't really see any reason why these shaders shouldn't compile or linke in a 3.3 context.